# Amazon VPC Availability

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-vpc, vpc

We are trying to expand our reliability setup using VPC in us-west-1. The 'a' and 'b' AZs work fine, but when I try to create subnets on 'c' it just fails with the message:

```
Value (us-west-1c) for parameter availabilityZone is invalid.
Subnets can currently only be created in the following availability zones:
    us-west-1b, us-west-1a.
```

Is this a transient failure or are there just only two VPC-enabled AZs in that region? If the latter, is there a list somewhere with how many AZs in each region are VPC-enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each AWS account has own set of the AZ. Get list of the available AZ you can help with AWS cli tools:

```
aws ec2 describe-availability-zones
```

See details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-availability-zones.html